# Parsing JSON to MYSQL Python 3

Tags: mysql, json, python-3.x

i want to parse JSON to mysql database with python 3. 
Lets say i have JSON from www.test.com/api/students contains list of students,

```
{
    contents: [
        {
            id:"a",
            name:"rey"
        },
        {
            id:"b",
            name:"rio"
        },
        {
            id:"c",
            name:"ramy"
        },
    ]
}
```

and i have database called "student" and table MSStudent contains "student_id" and "student_name".

How to parse this JSON and pass it to my database, and how i query it into model on python?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following methods:

Method 1: basic python

```
import json
json_data = json.loads("json string")
typ = type(json_data)
if typ == "dict":
    for key,value in json_data.items():
        print key+"=>"+val
        // insert in mysql (mysql query)
elif typ == "list":
    for k in json_data:
       print k
```

once you have parsed this, you may insert this in mysql.
Method 2: use pandas

PS: this is just pseudo code, you need to modify it, create one function and parse every key and value, this has worked for me even for GB's of json data.